# Remove Area name and Controller name from mvc routes in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to remove area name and controller name from URL.I am able to remove area name. But if trying to remove controller name then "Page not found error" displayed. Below is the code snippet which I have used to remove the area and controller name.

```
public class HomeAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Home";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        //context.MapRoute(
        //    "Home_default",
        //    "Home/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);

        //context.MapRoute(
        //   "Home_default",
        //   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //   new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        //   new { controller = "(Home)" }
        //);

        context.MapRoute(
           "Home_default",
           "{action}/{id}",
           new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new { controller = "(Home)" }
        );
    }
}
```

In the registerarea function the first two routes(commented) are working perfectly. if I use the first one the URL comes with Area/Controller/Action. If I use second one the area is not coming in URL.The URL come ups with Controller/Action.

In the third one I am trying to remove both area and Controller 
Is any thing wrong in my third route. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
routes.MapRoute("default", "{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Comment: Which url are you trying to map to what controller/action?

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new { area = "Home" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formHome" }))
{
} This is the form I am trying to map with a action "Index" , Controller "Home" and Area "Home".When I am trying to submit form I need to show only "index " in the url rather that /Home/Home/Index.